# Custom PolymerElements being constructed multiple times in conditional template

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have a custom polymer-element, "my-app" which uses template if="..." constructs to conditionally include other polymer elements.

All of these polymer elements are *defined* in one file, "views.html". This file includes the Dart code to implement all these custom elements, "views.dart".

I have a separate "index.html" that does nothing more than import the "views.html" file along with the standard polymer and dart initialization files, and then place a single my-app declaration tag in the body.

I am finding that the ".created" constructors for 1) the various subelements and 2) **the my-app element itself** (that conditionally includes subelements) are being **called multiple times** - even though a my-app element is **declared only once** in the simple "index.html" file.

I can see it right in the debugger.

Particularly regarding the calling of "MyApp.created", I thought this might be some garbage collection issue. But I set a global variable the first time MyApp is created to the MyApp instance to preclude this.

What is even stranger to me is that when MyApp is created repeatedly again, I can see that the global variable (to prevent gc of a MyApp instance) has been reset to "null", as if the entire file of Dart code had been reloaded/reevaluated somehow.

Very strange to me.

Are the PolymerElement subclasses for custom elements instantiated merely for the **definition** of custom elements? If so, that would be odd. I would think such custom polymer element subclasses would only be instantiated during the **declaration** of polymer elements.

Also, would a template conditional inside a polymer element definition somehow be able to force reconstruction of a the defined polymer element? This is hard to imagine, but then anything is possible with Dart Polymer, LOL!!!

I was looking for an authoritative document on when constructors for custom Dart PolymerElements might be called, but I could find no such document.

Any and all help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you make your code available (for example a GitHub repo). I haven't seen such a document yet and I work with Polymer for 1/2 year and follow the discussions on several sites.

Comment: Gunter, I have reorganized the code, separating some things into libraries and changed observable variables into getters so that I can better track what is going on in the Dart Editor debugger. Now I am wrestling a bit with the semantics of the "export" keyword instead, lol, but I think I'm getting a handle on libraries. I'll continue reassembling this simple app, track it in the debugger and report back on what I find. Thanks!

Comment: If you have something I should take a look on, just leave a comment then I get notified and when I find time I'll take a look. Or just create a new question.

Comment: I've simplified the app considerably. There are just three elements, one containing the other two, one conditionally and the other not. The contained elements are simply <h3> tags. Here is the definition of the  element that contains the two other elements.

Sorry, I'm going to put this in another stackoverflow question.

Comment: Gunter, I have simplified the app even more and reproduced peculiar results of very simple nested custom polymer dart elements. I've logged the code output to show order and frequency of construction and included a bit of the HTML element definitions. Love to know what you think.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Construction and ordering of nested and template if= style polymer dart elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22622969/construction-and-ordering-of-nested-and-template-if-style-polymer-dart-elements)