# Construction and ordering of nested and template if= style polymer dart elements?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, polymer

Code for a **very small** app illustrating these multiple constructor calls is now up on GitHub at https://github.com/Chiba-City/testnest.

I am trying to figure out

1. why a polymer element would be **constructed twice** and
2. what determines the order of construction of polymer elements that contain other polymer elements and
3. why is a "templated out" element using an "if" template constructed at all.

Also, if one cannot reproduce these results with three simple polymer elements, one defined to contain or nest the other two, I would also love to know that as well.

I am finding **duplicate constructor calls** and constructor ordering peculiarities. Here is an explanation of the occurrence of these peculiarities.

I have a very simple "app". There is an index.html file that html-includes a file of custom element definitions and declares just one custom polymer-dart element in its body. Here are the relevant portions of the index.html file. I have elided the customary boiler plate.

```dart
<!-- index.html -->
<!-- in head -->
<link rel="import" href="icapp.html">
<!-- boiler plate polymer/init.dart and ../dart.js stuff here -->

<!-- only contents of body tag -->
<icount-app></icount-app>
```

Now in "icapp.html" I define two elements consisting only of h3 labels. I contain these two elements in the template for a third element which begins with a simple H1 label. Here is the code for all three elements.

```dart
<!-- icapp.html -->
<!-- User stats list -->
<polymer-element name="icount-statlist" >
  <template><h3>My Stats</h3></template>
</polymer-element>

<!-- Find stats -->
<polymer-element name="icount-findstats" >
  <template><h3>Find New Stats</h3></template>
</polymer-element>

<!-- This is the element that contains the other two elements in its template -->
<polymer-element name="icount-app"> 
<template>
  <h1>icount.us</h1> <!-- a simple h1 heading -->

  <!-- Included always -->
  <icount-findstats></icount-findstats>

  <!-- Included conditionally - but can never be true -->
  <template if="{{false}}">
    <icount-statlist ></icount-statlist>
  </template>
<!-- End icount-app template -->
</template>
<!-- The code with the element definitions -->
<script type="application/dart" src="icapp.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

I have put "print" statements in the ".created() : super.created" constructors as well as overriden "enteredView()" methods to determine the order and frequency of these calls. Here is the output during execution. I have added notes prefixed with "--"

```dart
-- note this is first, although conditional on {{false}}
IcountStatlist: created           
-- now the containing element is constructed
IcountApp: created                
-- notice that enteredView happens before the nested element
IcountApp: enteredView
-- notice that this element is constructed twice
IcountFindstats: created          
IcountFindstats: created
IcountFindstats: enteredView
```

The output of the application is as expected (H1 and an H3 tags, the latter for the non-conditionally included "icount-findstats" element). But how it arrives here is peculiar, and in ways that would seem to defy adding reasonable program logic to these tags (properties, event handlers and so on).

1. The visible nested element is constructed twice
2. The "templated out" nested element is constructed once
3. The visible nested element's "enteredView" method is called (not surprisingly).

Above the contained visible element is constructed **after** the containing element. But simple experimentation shows that **this ordering seems arbitrary**, or at least, not dependent on templating or ordering of nested elements.

If we simply switch our preference for which nested element we "template out" we get the following output instead.

```dart
IcountStatlist: created
IcountStatlist: created
IcountStatlist: enteredView
IcountApp: created
IcountApp: enteredView
IcountFindstats: created
```

Here we can note:

1. The visible nested element, this time icount-statlist, is constructed twice, as above, but created **before** the containing element. Also the HTML output h3 tag occurs only once.
2. This visible nested element's "enteredView" method is called **prior** to the containing element.
3. The "templated out" nested element is again created (just once), but now **after** the containing element.

Further experimentation shows that the same element non-conditionally, visibly nested **twice** results in **4 constructor calls** (for that element).

Another experiment shows that the same element conditionally contained twice results in **2 constructor calls** (for that element).

Experimenting with reordering the "templated out" element and the visible element reveals no change in log output, i.e., the order or frequency of constructor calls.

Needless to say, I am perplexed.

- Why is the visible nested element constructed **twice** ?
- Why is the "templated out" nested element constructed **at all** ?
- Why is one nested element constructed **before** the containing element and the other **after** ?
- Why is the **containing** element, icount-app, itself **not** constructed twice?
- How can a **containing element** sensibly **set properties** of contained elements given nature and ordering of custom polymer element (object) construction?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about posting the entire project on GitHub? Its a lot of work to rebuild a project that makes this reproducable and there are lots of possibilities one can make different which makes it hard to discuss.

Comment: Here is the code in a public [git repo - https://github.com/Chiba-City/testnest](https://github.com/Chiba-City/testnest) This is my first time pushing a Dart project. Let me know if you have any issues with it. Thanks so much for helping. It's a tiny project that just illustrates the anomalies with print() statemenst

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE**

- `enteredView` was changed to `attached`
- `leftView` to `detached`

**-------**

I tried your code and I can't reproduce the things you mentioned.

This is the output I got when I run your app:

```
nest-a: created
nest-a: enterView
nest-container: created
nest-container: enteredView
nest-b: created
nest-b: enteredView
```

- the nested `nest-b` is not instantiated at all (the output is from the `nest-b` outside the `<template if="{{false}}">`

after changing `false` to `true` I get

```
nest-a: created
nest-a: enterView
nest-container: created
nest-container: enteredView
nest-b: created
nest-b: enteredView
nest-b: created
nest-b: enteredView
```

You need to put the value in quotes `="{{false}}"` instead of `={{false}}`
It worked as expected anyway because this was evaluated to false as well but would fail for all other values/expressions

- I don't know if the construction order is settled.
  Recently there was still a discussion whether it should be constucted inside out or document order.
  If you use binding this normally isn't an issue

Can you please post the output you got from the app you published to the GitHub repo?

Comment: So you are saying that solved it? I guess a stable 1.3 will be published soon (can't say how soon though).

Comment: Gunter, Yes, the multiple constructor call problem went away! Amazing, maybe suppose no one is using the stable build? :) Fingers crossed that now I can start writing some "real code." Lol... Thanks again!

Comment: It would be nice if you could accept my answer by clicking on the check mark below the up-vote icon.

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurred in the following stable release of Dart Editor.

```
$ dart --version 
Dart VM version: 1.2.0 (Tue Feb 25 07:34:09 2014) on "linux_x64"
```

Installation of the latest **dev channel** build of Dart SDK made the multiple constructor calls go away.

```
$ dart --version
Dart VM version: 1.3.0-dev.6.1 (Sat Mar 22 02:14:22 2014) on "linux_x64"
```

The output of the **testnest** project is now:

```
nest-a: created
nest-a: enterView
nest-container: created
nest-container: enteredView
nest-b: created
nest-b: enteredView
```

How to **code around the order of nested element construction** - both **before** and **after** the containing element - in Dart code remains an open exercise for the reader :)